# window.location.href isn't working

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using this script on javascript to change location and get some variable in the url but **window.location.href**    didn't work i can't redirect to another page

during some search i found i need to put **return false;**

i put it but also i don't have any result

R: No error message appear

How to solve that ?

```js
function getPosition() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successPosition);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Your browser does not support geo location api"
  }

  function successPosition(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Latitude:" + lat + "<br/>Longitude:" + long
    window.location.href = "facee.php?lat=" + lat + "&long=" + long;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return getPosition();">
  <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="camera" class="filestyle" data-buttonBefore="true" data-iconName="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" data-buttonText="Take apicture." />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

Comment: 1. You need to `return getPosition()` 2. it is better to use the onsubmit 3. You return from a nested function instead of the one called 4. you want to change the location AND upload the image? Then you need to return the new location from the form submit

Comment: @mplungjan i changed  return false to return getPosition(); and onclick="getPosition();" to onsubmit="getPosition();"  and also didn't work

Comment: No You need to do `onsubmit="return getPosition();" ` and in the function getPosition() you need to return false.

Comment: Changes to `location.href` are ignored, while a server call is pending. If you don't want to submit the form, then don't even start. Use type of button instead of type of submit for the button.

Comment: onsubmit event should be attached to the form, not the input/submit.

Comment: Your query string is missing the & in front of "long" - window.location.href = "facee.php?lat=" + lat + "&long=" + long;

Comment: @mplungjan i did what you say but it still not working you can check the code above

Comment: your `successPosition` function is in inside the `getPosition` function. Define it outside of the scope of `getPosition` function.

Comment: @LahiruAshan nothing happen still not working and when i click the submit button the form is not submiting

Comment: @mplungjan any other idea ?!

Comment: @mhmd form is not submitting because you return `false` from `getPosition()` function. what exactly want you to do, form submit or redirect page to a another URL?

Comment: I already said _you want to change the location AND upload the image? Then you need to return the new location from the form submit_ You can use a button and then setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("myFormID").submit() },3000);` if you want to show something and later submit

Comment: @mplungjan when i choose the image i click the submit button and i want to change the location and get the variables the upload code is in the page put it  here  window.location.href = "facee.php?lat=" + lat + "&long=" + long;

Comment: @LahiruAshan when i choose the image i click the submit button and i want to change the location and get the variables the upload code is in the page put it here window.location.href = "facee.php?lat=" + lat + "&long=" + long;

Comment: You cannot upload an image file while changing location. What is the aim of the form?

Comment: @mhmd are you trying change form submit location, I mean form `action`

Comment: @LahiruAshan yes action when i click the submit button i go to another page using the javascript and in the other page i will get lat and long variable and i will do my upload code

Comment: @mhmd is that *mplungjan* answer is the solution you are searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, I THINK you want this

```js
function successPosition(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude,
    long = position.coords.longitude,
    form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Submitting Latitude:" + lat + "<br/>Longitude:" + long;
  form.lat.value = lat;
  form.long.value = long;
  form.submit(); // HERE we submit
};

function getPosition() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successPosition);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Your browser does not support geo location api ";
  }
  return false; // always block submission
}
```

using

```html
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="facee.php" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return getPosition();">
  <input type="hidden" name="lat" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="long" value="" />
  <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="camera" class="filestyle" data-buttonBefore="true" data-iconName="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" data-buttonText="Take apicture." />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href = "facee.php?lat="+lat+"long="+long;`
should be
`window.location.href = "facee.php?lat="+lat+"&long="+long;`
maybe you miss an '&'.

Comment: That is the least of his problems. Also it is already commented

Answer (score 0):

Don't overcrowd your code functions.
How to solve your redirection issue
`window.location.href = "/facee.php?lat="+lat+"&long="+long;`

However, this is not the only issue in your code.
You are doing a lot of things not right

#### 1:

```
function getPosition() {
//...
    function successPosition(position) {
```

Every time you call `getPosition`, you are redefining the `sucessPosition`

#### 2:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Latitude:" + lat + "<br/>Longitude:" + long
window.location.href = "facee.php?lat=" + lat + "long=" + long;
```

If your code was working, this would "print" the geolocation in the page and immediately redirect you. The user can't never see that `result` print.

#### 3:

```
return false;
```

Why?

Comment: how to solve it ?

Answer (score -1):

Define the function before use it.
It works fine on https://jsfiddle.net/jerrysin/q0hck8as/

```
<script>
  function successPosition(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Latitude:" + lat + "<br/>Longitude:" + long;
    window.location.href = "facee.php?lat=" + lat + "long=" + long;
    return false;
  };

  function getPosition() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successPosition);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Your browser does not support geo location api ";
    }
  };

</script>

<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="camera" class="filestyle" data-buttonBefore="true" data-iconName="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" data- buttonText="Take apicture." />
  <div id="result"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" onclick="getPosition();">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: Did you define successPosition(position) before you call getPosition()?

Comment: That is not the problem. He does not return getPosition in the button so the form submits before it is executed

Comment: @mplungjan can you please put the right way of the code ?!

Comment: @mplungjan the javascript code give me long and lat when i click the submit button of the form i want to redirect to another page using javascript ("action") and have the variables lat and long and in the other page i will get this variable from the url

Answer (score -2):

change your code

```
window.location.href = "facee.php?lat="+lat+"long="+long;
```

to this:

```
document.location= "facee.php?lat="+lat+"&long="+long;
```

Comment: No. That is not correct. [document.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location) is read-only location object and may not have the expected side-effect of changing location

Comment: he said that he can't redirect to another page. document.location may help

Comment: No it may not. It is not the problem. window.location="url" or window.location.href="url" will redirect if called correctly - and you ALSO miss the &

Comment: ok. url would be the problem. ;)

Comment: change the url to fix the problem

Comment: mplungjan got the correct answer